Angle between imaginary axis and its image under möbius transformation
Let $m:\overline{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}}
$ be the Möbius transform $m(z) = \frac{cos(\alpha)z-sin(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)z+cos(\alpha)}$ and let $I$ be the imaginary axis. $m$ leaves $i$ fixed.
Prove that the angle between $I$ and $m(I)$ at $i$ is $2\alpha$, measured from $I$ to $m(I)$.
I already know that a Möbius transform maps circles in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ to circles in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ and is conformal (angles stay the same). In our case $m$ also maps $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, so $m(I)$ makes an 90° angle with $m(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$.
My attempt was to look at $\infty, 0 \in I$, both their images lie in $\mathbb{R}$: $m(\infty)=\frac{cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m(0)=\frac{-sin(\alpha)}{cos(\alpha)} \in \mathbb{R}$. So $m(I)$ is a circle $A$ with its center $C$ on $\mathbb{R}$ through the points $m(\infty)$, $m(0)$ and $i$. To determine the angle between $A$ and $I$, I tried to find the slope of the tangent at $A$ in $i$: The center of this circle is $\frac{m(\infty)+m(0)}{2}$, so the line $l$ connecting $i$ and $C$ has slope $\frac{1-0}{0-(m(\infty)+m(0))/2}$. The tangent through $i$ is perpendicular to $l$, thus has slope $\frac{m(\infty)+m(0)}{2}=\frac{cos(\alpha)^2-sin(\alpha)^2}{2sin(\alpha)cos(\alpha)}=\frac{1-2sin(\alpha)^2}{2sin(\alpha)cos(\alpha)}$. Now, take $\pi-tan(\frac{1-2sin(\alpha)^2}{2sin(\alpha)cos(\alpha)})$ and this should be equal to $2\alpha$. I don't know how to simplify this expression and maybe there is an easier way to show this.

Have you made any attemps? What are your thoughts?

Maybe that $m$ is elliptic, so can be written as $m(z)=e^{2i\alpha}z$, which is a rotation about the origin by $2\alpha$.
